# How to use django template tags on returned AJAX calls?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a simple AJAX script that takes an inputted string in a searchfield named `AJAXBox` and calls a view function that queries the database with a filter and returns a queryset of all User objects that match the entered parameter. When I go to iterate through the queryset with django template tags, it does not work. I assume it is because the output for my Javascript call does not actually output the queryset but some type of string that django template does not recognize. How can I fix this so that my AJAX calls return the true django compatible querysets that the normal render function in django outputs?

The JS for the AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#AJAXBox').keyup(function()  {

    var searchedterm;
    searchedterm = $(this).val();
    $.get('/AJAXsearch/', {searchterm: searchedterm}, function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);

      });       

    });  
});
```

The tl;dr for the python code is essentially:

```
def AJAXsearch(request):
    searchterm = request.GET['searchterm']
    result = UserObj.objects.filter(person_name=searchterm)
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

When I go to my html in my template and do something like:

```
<div id="result">
    {% for person in result %}
        {{person.property}}
    {%endfor%}
</div>
```

The template tag loop does not do anything. In fact, I cannot manipulate/design the output at all, it is just a normal string of usernames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't calling your template in your view.

Try this instead:

```
def AJAXsearch(request):
    searchterm = request.GET['searchterm']
    result = UserObj.objects.filter(person_name=searchterm)
    return render(request,"path/to/your/template.html", {"result":result})
```

Based on the comments you are reusing the main code for your page with the code for generating your `<div>` block.

In that case I'd recommend pulling that block into a separate file, say `"resultlist.html"` and [including that in your main template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include) so:

`resultlist.html`:

```
<div id="result" >
{% for person in result %}
{{person.property}}
{%endfor%} </div>
```

Then in `userprofile.html`:

```
{# Lots of code around the result list #}
{% include "resultlist.html" %}
{# Lots of code around the result list #}
```

Comment: That seems to have worked! However, the template I am using to format the results is used for the design of the entire page as well so whenever the AJAXsearch function is evoked and the template is rendered, it renders the entire page again inside the result div with the result variable. How can I get the render function to only apply to particular div inside of the template if that is possible? I tried creating an entirely new html template for the ajax results and had the AJAXsearch function render that as the output, but it didn't work.

Comment: You've obviously got other code in your template then. Can you post the rest?

Comment: Ya, I do. I'm not truncating it for privacy or anything, just for the sake of brevity. It's basically just a bunch of code for rendering different parts of the user profile page. Just blocks of html/variables. The result div is just placed right under the search bar on the page. What is essentially happening is that when I make an ajax call now using your fix, a smaller/new entire user profile page gets loaded all within the result div tag with the correct search results inside that. But clearly, I only want the result div to be rendered, not another instance of the ENTIRE template.

Comment: @EazyC I've updated the answer, basically you'll need a template *just for* the result list, and perhaps include that into the main template.