# Can't get all comments to reload without page refresh after comment submitted thourgh ajax

Tags: ajax, django

I have been trying to come up with a scheme where the comments sections refreshes in a template when a user posts comments with the comment that was just posted being included. The page must not be refreshed.

Sorry for indentation.

template -

```
     {% extends "home/header.html" %}

     {% block content %}

     {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

    <form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Comment: </p><input type="text" name="fname" id="posted_comment">
    <input type="hidden" class='meme_char_id' meme_char_id={{meme.meme_char_id}}>
    <input type="submit"  id ="btnSubmit" name="submit" value="Post">
    </form>

    <!-- displaying comments here -->
    <div class="box" id="comments_div">
        <h3 class="h4">{{comment_count}} comments  </h4>
            <ul class="list-group">
            {% for comment in all_comments %}
            <h5>{{ comment.commentby.username }} : </h5>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">{{ comment.comment_text }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
    </div>

     {% endif %}

     {% endblock %}
```

Now, my JS file is -

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var data = new FormData();
             var comment = $('#posted_comment').val()
             var meme_char_id = $(".meme_char_id").attr('meme_char_id')
             data.append('comment', comment);
             data.append('meme_char_id', meme_char_id);
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '<mydomain>/comment/',
                 data: data,
                 processData: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 success: function(reply) {
                     $(".comments_div").html(reply)
                 }
             })
         });
     });
```

And finally my view is -

```
    def comment(request):

    if request.is_ajax():
    comment = request.POST['comment']
    meme_char_id = request.POST['meme_char_id']
    this_meme = Memes.objects.get(meme_char_id=meme_char_id)
    print "comment - ", comment, " meme_char_id - ", meme_char_id
    new_comment = Comments(comment_text=comment, meme_id=this_meme.meme_id, commentby_id=request.user.id)
    new_comment.save()
    all_comments = Comments.objects.filter(meme_id=this_meme.meme_id).order_by('-created_at').values()
    return HttpResponse(all_comments, content_type='application/json')
else:
    raise Http404
```

Couple questions -

1. I want to return an Comments query set through ajax(don't see a point in jsonifying it, if I can just send the query set to the template.)
2. The queryset I am returning to template isn't picked up by the comments_div in the view.

I am a rookie so please explain step by step what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: For folks who come here for similar situation. [this link helped me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158658/how-to-use-django-template-tags-on-returned-ajax-calls)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending back a JSON in a response and doing`$(".comments_div").html(reply)`. You must be sending back a template rendered with `all_comments` as response on successful comment. Also, a queryset is not JSON serializable as far as I understand.